# Switching PHP version with MacPort

Tags: php, macports, versions

I've installed PHP 5.4 with MacPorts, using all the ports I had on my current PHP 5.3.
I then (foolishly) ran the command `sudo port select --set php php54` and received `Selecting 'php54' for 'php' succeeded. 'php54' is now active.`

However, I couldn't run any of my current PHP pages, receiving a 'Forbidden' error from Apache. I decided to switch back to 5.3, and ran `sudo port select --set php php5` only to receive `Selecting 'php5' for 'php' failed: The specified version 'php5' is not valid.`. I tried the same with php53 - and got the same message.

To verify what's installed I ran `port installed php*` and got:

`php5 @5.3.28_0+apache2+pear (active)
  php5-apc @3.1.9_1 (active)
  php5-curl @5.3.28_0 (active)
  php5-iconv @5.3.28_0 (active)
  php5-mbstring @5.3.28_0 (active)
  php5-mcrypt @5.3.28_0 (active)
  php5-memcache @2.2.7_0 (active)
  php5-mysql @5.3.28_0+mysqlnd (active)
  php5-openssl @5.3.28_0 (active)
  php5-xdebug @2.2.5_0 (active)
  php54 @5.4.30_0+libedit (active)
  php54-apache2handler @5.4.30_0 (active)
  php54-APC @3.1.13_0 (active)
  php54-curl @5.4.30_0 (active)
  php54-iconv @5.4.30_0 (active)
  php54-mbstring @5.4.30_0 (active)
  php54-mcrypt @5.4.30_0 (active)
  php54-memcache @2.2.7_0 (active)
  php54-mysql @5.4.30_0+mysqlnd (active)
  php54-openssl @5.4.30_0 (active)
  php54-xdebug @2.2.5_0 (active)
  php_select @1.0_0 (active)`

So, there are 2 version of PHP installed. How do I switch back to PHP 5.3? And why is running 5.4 encounters a permissions issue?

Comment: Why not fix the problem with Apache instead?

Comment: Done :) Still, since I haven't changed any of my PHP code, I'll feel safer switching back to 5.3.

Comment: Well then, maybe (and im not sure here) you could just do sudo port deactivate php54. (however, since this is server stuff, the question as a whole is more appropriate for [serverfault](http://serverfault.com) than SO)

Comment: Is there any way to transfer the question to ServerFault?

Comment: TBH, you should just post it there as a new question so it gets on top of the list. If it is xfered, I think it keeps your creation date. (not sure but wouldnt take the risk)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Well, I haven't been able to revert to 5.3. I ended up fixing the access rights error, and I'm currently using 5.4. Fortunately, it's backwards compatible (at least, I have not hit on anything significant yet).

Bottom line - be careful with Ports activations - there may be no (known) going back.

Answer (score 11):

Maybe it's a good idea to ask `port` which post are available by invoking:

```
sudo port select --list php
```

Then you get a list of all the `php` versions port knows about

You can only do

```
sudo port select --set php <onOfTheList>
```

In my case, it was a `python` port, and `port select --list python` gave me a `python26-apple`. To get back to this known port, I had to enter

```
sudo port select --set python python27-apple
```

and this made the reverse.